# long long multiplication in C gives wrong result

Tags: c, gcc

My C code seems to be malfunctioning and incapable of multiplying long long numbers and outputting the result, and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Here's the culprit code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
  unsigned long long primes[] = {199453LL, 200723LL, 203317LL, 205103LL, 206603LL, 208057LL, 210323LL, 210961LL, 212827LL, 214237LL, 215693LL, 216319LL};
  unsigned long long numbers[6];

  int i;
  printf("Calculating the numbers to factor!\n");
  printf("Size of long: %i\n", sizeof(long));
  printf("Size of long long: %i\n", sizeof(long long));
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
    numbers[i] = primes[i]*primes[11-i];
    printf("%ld*%ld = %ld\n", primes[i], primes[11-i], numbers[i]);
    printf("Result is %ld\n",numbers[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And here's the output when I compile this and run it (I'm using gcc version 4.8.2 on Linux)

```
Calculating the numbers to factor!
Size of long: 4
Size of long long: 8
199453*0 = 216319
Result is 195800547
200723*0 = 215693
Result is 344873079
203317*0 = 214237
Result is 608351169
205103*0 = 212827
Result is 701783221
206603*0 = 210961
Result is 635502523
208057*0 = 210323
Result is 809499451
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `printf` format string is wrong. `%ld` requires a `long int`, `%lld` is for a `long long int`, and since you are using `unsigned long long`, you should use `%llu`, otherwise large positive values will be displayed as negative.

And, as noticed by [Grzegorz Szpetkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099645/long-long-multiplication-in-c-gives-wrong-result/28099676#comment44575186_28099676), the `size_t` (`sizeof`) requires `%zu`.

From *printf(3)*:

> `l`      (ell)  A following integer conversion corresponds to a `long int` or `unsigned long int` argument, or a following n conversion
>   corresponds to a pointer to a `long int` argument, or a following `c` conversion corresponds to a `wint_t` argument, or a following `s` conversion corresponds to a pointer to `wchar_t` argument.
>
> `ll`    (ell-ell).  A following integer conversion corresponds to a `long long int` or `unsigned long long int` argument, or a following
>   `n` conversion corresponds to a pointer to a
>                 `long long int` argument.
>
> **...**
>
> `z`  A following integer conversion corresponds to a `size_t` or `ssize_t` argument.  (Linux libc5 has Z with this meaning.  Don't use it.)

---

Now, for example this output

```
199453*0 = 216319
```

Occurs because the little-endian 64-bit numbers 199453, 216319 and 43145473507 are correctly pushed onto the stack; but `printf` expects to find only 32-bit numbers on the stack, so it prints 199453, 0 (which are the top 4 bytes of 64-bit number 199453), and 216319.

Comment: In addition to this `sizeof` operator yields value of type `size_t`. The correct format specifier for it is `%zu`.

Comment: Should be `%llu` since they are `unsigned long long`.